# Symfony2 - redirect logged in users when entering anonymous areas

Tags: symfony, security, authorization

I created an action that handles redirection to respected areas depending on user's type and ROLE (trainee, company or university let's say). If user is not logged in, it redirects to homepage (anonymous area), and if logged in - to their profile pages. I use it in homepage and many other cases, for example, as sign up and login success redirection.

```
public function authorizationAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

    $request->cookies->remove('action');

    if ($user) {
        if ($user->getType() == 'company' && $authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_COMPANY_GUEST')) {
            /** @var Company $company */
            $company = $user->getCompany();
            if ($user->getState() == 'active' && $company->getState() == 'active') {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('company');
            } else {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('company_profile');
            }
        } elseif ($user->getType() == 'university' && $authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_UNIVERSITY_GUEST')) {
            /** @var University $university */
            $university = $user->getUniversity();
            if ($user->getState() == 'active' && $university->getState() == 'active') {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('university');
            } else {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('university_profile');
            }
        } elseif ($user->getType() == 'trainee' && $authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_TRAINEE')) {
            /** @var Trainee $trainee */
            $trainee = $user->getTrainee();
            if ($user->getState() == 'active' && $trainee->getState() == 'active') {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('trainee');
            } else {
                $response = $this->redirectToRoute('trainee_profile');
            }
        } else {
            $response = $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }
    } else {
        $response = $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I have seen some [examples](https://coderwall.com/p/w0yyag/redirect-authenticated-user-on-anonymous-pages-in-symfony) recommending using symfony events (`kernel.request`) to handle it minimizing controller code. But in this case I will not be able to use this action as sign up and login success path.

I am not using `FOS`, because of lack of user customization. I prefer handling User my self.

Is my approach wrong and something to be worried about?

Some things that I am concerned:

1. Redirection count:

For example. I am logged in user and I go to homepage and am redirected to my action where I am checked whether I am logged in or not and depending on user type I am redirected to respected page.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('authorization');
    }

    // ...

}
```

2. Slowing website:

In the future I will be using this action in more pages and website will definatelly slow down everytime executing same code on each page.

Comment: What does this mean? "But in this case I will not be able to use this action as sign up and login success path."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not using FOS, because of lack of user customization. I prefer handling User my self.
>   Blockquote

You really shouldn't reinvent the wheel here but even if you want to your assessment that extending FOS is hard is wrong, take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697) how many of us Symfony Devs extend FOS to enable social login via HWIOauthBundle. Extending it for other purposes is equally trivial.

Update Since OP's Comments Below

....

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken;
use AppBundle\Form\Type\LoginType;
```

....

....

```
$login_form = $this->createForm(LoginType::class);
$login_form->handleRequest($request);

if (!$login_form->isValid()){
    //throw error
}

$email = strip_tags($login_form->get('email')->getData());
$password = $login_form->get('password')->getData();

// Call the User Manager
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($email);

if(!$user){
    //throw error : User With Submitted Credentials Does Not Exist
}

$user_password = $user->getPassword();
$encoded_password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $password);

if($encoded_password != $user_password){
    //throw error : Wrong Password, Please Check Your Details & Re-submit
}

// Successful query of username/email and password now we log in user

// Create new token
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());

// Login New User
$tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
$tokenStorage->setToken($token);

// User now logged in
$user_id = $user->getId();
```

....

> Redirection count:

In your case each redirection would cause at least 1 database query to verify user session, so yes many them could lead to a bad use and server experience. If you use FOSUserBundle with Doctrine's Second Level Cache, you can avoid this query everytime you call $this->getUser();

> Slowing website:

This very small bit of code with hardly be you bottleneck at scale but for arguments sake let's assume it is. I would solve this problem by introducing client side sessions. A framework like Angular or my personal favorite Ember would allow you to store user sessions on the client so as not to even bother going back to your server all the time for such a menial task as checking authentication or roles. I would still advise you to keep some server side code for those cheeky users who want to poke holes in your code.

Comment: Because I have two sign up forms for different user types in one page and as I remember it is very complicated for FOS to manage that. Also my login form is in the same page as registration. Also login form is in multiple ofther pages. In my case FOS is harder than reinventing the wheel.

Anyway, you based your answer on FOS which I am against. Answer is worthless in my case. Anyway I will not use Angular in my Symfony project. Project is not that complicated. Thank you anyway.

Comment: With all due respect your requirements are nothing new, login forms on every page is easily done in SYmfony with and without FOSUserBundles  although the former makes it easier and most importantly tried tested and secure, see my updated example of how to login user.

Comment: Lastly, I believe my answer does answer your question, the best way to avoid redirection performance hit is either to completely avoid doing it (by client side frameworks) or to at least cache the most demanding parts of it e.g with FOSUserBundle and Doctrine Second Level Cache, alternatively, you can role out your own in which case you can only get help on SO if your code has specific issues for people to look at.

Answer (score 0):

The Access Control section in the Symfony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) might offer easier solutions to restrict access. In my time using Symfony I have always been able to use it for redirection and access control.